# Angular js search input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have below search input box:

```
<div id="query-wrap">
            <input ng-enter="startSearch('{{queryObj.query}}')" id="query" type="text" ng-model="queryObj.query"
                placeholder="Enter Query" autocomplete="off"  />
</div>
<a class="searchButton" ng-click='startSearch(queryObj.query)'>Search</a>
```

on click of search I am calling `startsearch` function:

```
$scope.startSearch = function(query) {
            console.log("query is ::" + query);
                            
            //  $location.path("/view");
                $location.search({
                                    q:query
                });
                                
                getData();
                                                                
}
```

Issue is: After submit is clicked proper query parameter is appended in the URL but sometimes query entered in search box is getting disappeared because of which I am not able to see proper results.

Below is my ng-enter directive:

```
app.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs, dropdownService) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            
            if(event.which === 13) {  
                //If user presses an enter then fire an ESC event to not to show a dropdown
                var e = angular.element.Event("keydown");                    
                e.which = 27;
                element.trigger(e);                  
                scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);               
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`startSearch('{{queryObj.query}}')` should be `startSearch(queryObj.query)`. There's no reason to wrap that in an expression.